# When we create Button frame within for loop then now we want to remove or clean button frame then how can do this?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

When we create Button frame within for loop then now we want to remove or clean button frame then how can do this ?

```
for(int i=0 ;i<(self.WebService->ptr1).count ;i++)
{

     Test1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];
    [Test1 addTarget:self action:@selector(TestDescription1:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    Test1.tag=i;
    NSLog(@"test =%d",Test1.tag);
    NSString *s1 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.WebService->ptr1 objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"Description"]];
    NSLog(@"s1 =%@",s1);

    NSString *s2 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.WebService->ptr1 objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"TestId"]];
    NSLog(@"s2 =%@",s2);
    [TestID addObject:s2];
    NSLog(@"test id=%@",TestID);
    [Test1 setTitle:s1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [scrollview addSubview:Test1];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(TestDescription1:)];

    [Test1 addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    Test1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

     y=y+40;

}
```

then now remove button frame when we want to again start for loop ....in this case if ARRYA.count is 4 then 4 frame set but we want to next time Arrya.count is 2 but last to frame is not remove ....What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this method will remove all the buttons in your scrollview,

Call this method when you want to remove old Buttons in the scrollview.

```
-(void) removeMyButtons{

    for(UIView *v in scrollview.subviews){
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
            [v removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are re-allocating button release button in for loop like..

**IF YOU ARE NOT USING ARC**

```
for(int i=0 ;i<(self.WebService->ptr1).count ;i++)
{
     Test1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];

     /// Your Code......

     [Test1 release];
}
```

then to remove all buttons use this

```
-(void) removeAllButtons{
    for(UIButton *btn in scrollview.subviews){
            [btn removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write this code before your for loop in which you add all buttons.
that means you remove all button before the adding all buttons.

```
for (UIView* subView in scrollview.subviews)  {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        [subView removeFromSuperview];
}
```